# What's the purpose of splitting Stack Exchange into many sub-sites?

Tags: discussion

We can just specify  the question with tags, whatever it's mathematics or programming and etc. The homepage will have tabs that will show questions with specified tags.

The problem that it solves is when you have a question that is programming-mathematics for example and it's balanced between so you need the help of both communities or ones that is interested in both programming and mathematics.

If it solves problems like that, that even will make the site more interesting with new varieties of questions. Why is it splitted?

Comment: What's the positive of having an "everything under the sun" site? Why would that be a good thing?

Comment: @Oded Actually the reasons start at the third line and ends at the end of the post. (Sorry for getting too obvious)

Comment: The single responsibility principle.

Comment: @KugBuBu - but how does that benefit everyone (that is, most people - who are interested in one **or** the other)?

Comment: Spot on. With tags, we already had very dynamic categories. I think neither system is perfect. But having both walled off tags and rigid categories is worse than either on its own. However, a hybrid system where some tags would hold over several domains would be better. Or, if there was some kind of synchronisation system. For example, for all the sites that sprung up from Overflow, the pertinent tags for the new sites should carry over. The back linking could also be made possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can see many good reasons:

- **Help pages.** For a lot of tags, a different on-topic and off-topic help page would need to be created, and that's harder to manage than if you have different help pages per site.
- **Privileges.** If you would get 3,000 rep from programming questions, then you would also be able to close math questions, for example, which is not desired, and having privileges per-site is easier than having privileges per-tag.
- **Close reasons.** It would be necessary to have close reasons per-tag, and again, it's easier to have close reasons per-site than per-tag.
- **Beta sites.** There are many beta sites in the network. How are you going to solve that? Beta tags, and different privileges for a beta tag? Again, it is *a lot* easier to have this on a different site.
- **Moderators.** Instead of a site moderator, you would need a tag moderator. Again, it is a lot easier to have a moderator per-site instead of per-tag.
- **Meta sites.** You would also need a meta per-tag, instead of a meta per-site. Again, it is easier to have a meta per site.

So if you take all those reasons in account, it is a lot easier to have a site for a specifc topic than a tag for a specific topic.

Comment: You can just make the tags "special" that it'll add certain options to it. The Privileges is something, but there's things like able to close question in one flag when you help a lot in one tag. So it's already here. (You can split the "special" tags too) But I see that it's just a lot of efforts. Accepted.

Comment: I just started asking a question along the similar lines like KugBuBu. The problem is that the categories are not at all *specific*. As an example, there is a Computational Science site and , then, there is Stack Overflow. Both contain *fftw* tag. Q&A for both are now isolated , so you actually lose expertise. The notion of fixed categories with no restrictions on tags clashes with the notion of using tags to classify the answers. The rigid system is bad. At least some tags should have validity across the categories. I understand that this problem arose historically.

Comment: @MaliRemorker If every question should be categorized under a "special" tag (if the sites would be split), then the problem would still exist: under which tag? Computational Science or programming? I would say that both should not be possible, for reasons of privileges and reputation.

Comment: Your reputation is question-based , I don't suggest you get it twice for one question. If two categories have overlap, it's only fair that it is somehow acknowledged on both category sites.  Regarding your question, i don't see the problem. A special tag would mean that corpus of questions is equally valid for both sites. Tag fftw is an example. On the other hand, tag "pseudo-spectral method" should only work on Comp. Sci. as well as "I/0" on SO.

Comment: @MaliRemorker Yes, there are overlapping tags, but that should not be a reason to create one site for everything, because of the problems I listed in my answer. Overlapping tags are really not a problem, you should just pick the site where your question fits best on.

Comment: The problem arises when you want to search for knowledge. Browsing tag *fftw* on Comp. Sci returns cca 10-20 questions. Browsing the same on SO gives you loads more. At least, this was my experience.

Comment: @MaliRemorker You can always use Google to search for something, or do a Network Search on stackexchange.com.

Comment: True, but browsing a tag within a particular category may then fail to provide you with the full information. For me, this is aesthetically displeasing. Moreover, it does not follow the principle of least surprise for the user. Also, you may unwittingly duplicate the question, because the "related questions" list which appears once you start typing the title,  works only within a certain category. One solution is to migrate tags to wherever the overlords of Stack Exchange deem they fit best. Then at least you retain uniqueness, although sometimes the choices are not clear cut.

Comment: @MaliRemorker That's correct, but that as only reason is not enough to merge all sites. Many other problems would arise.

Comment: @MaliRemorker Problem is, just because a tag exists on a site does not mean every question about that subject belongs on that site.  It's that subject, *and that expertise*, that make up what you can and can't ask.  If your example question would be valid on both CompSci and SO, then you need to refine the question more.  Is the problem in the programming?  Or does it fit into CompSci's expertise more?  If you still answer, "Both", then you need to continue to refine the problem, until it only belongs on one site.

Comment: @fbueckert I don't think this reduction is always possible. This is not an SO problem only, it is also an old philosophical problem. But, from the practical point of view, one issue can start as looking more technical at the beginning, only that you find after you and others delve deeper into topic that the problem lies somewhere else. Therefore a tag can be a time dependent quantity. However, I don't care how the content is categorised as long as there is a unified means of accessing all the relevant content across the entire Stack Exchange and in all places one would expect.

Answer (score 6):

One of the best reasons to split the sites is the whole reason people stick around:  **Expertise**.

No one is an expert in everything at all.  This way, each site has their own, narrowly scoped area.  Gamers don't need to worry about cooking, programmers don't need to worry about christianity, and spiritual people don't need to worry about gamers, cooking, or programmers.

The site is dedicated to only a single, specific area, and you can create the site's identity from the community around that expertise.  Granted, there are things that don't work on any SE site, such as discussions or resource requests, but you can help shape the community of what you're interested in.

Tagging doesn't help in any of that sense, as users can (and will) mistag.  It happens on a depressingly regular basis.  It would only get incredibly worse if you jumbled all the sites (and all their content) into a single area.

Also, in regards to a question that would be on-topic at two different sites, I've always been of the opinion that's an indicator that you haven't thought the question through enough.  If it's that general, you need to focus it more, until you get closer to the root of your problem.

Comment: the two first segments -> my tab idea. It's now about getiing all the content into one place, you can separate those by tabs. It's about making question that need knowledge from two communities.

Comment: And as I said, if it needs knowledge from two communities, *you haven't thought it through enough*.  It's still too vague.  Spend more time thinking about the root issue.  As for tabs, why?  What benefit does it give?  You have not provided any advantages over the existing system.

Comment: "you haven't thought it through enough" I think I got it, you mean maybe how to separate the question or something like that. OK then really it doesn't matter.